# How to match/search for a specific pattern but not having another specific pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I need to match for a pattern `not check` in a bigger string.

```
bigger_string = '<some words and> do not check <some other words>'
```

But it shouldn't have a number after that. So, `not check <some words>` should match but `not check 67 <some words>` shouldn't match.
I tried these:

```
re.findall(re.compile(r'not\s*check\s*\D*', re.I), bigger_string)

re.findall(re.compile(r'not\s*check\s*[^0-9]*', re.I), bigger_string)
```

It doesn't work. This always returns a match.

Comment: Try: `r'\bnot\s+check(?!\s*\d)'`

Comment: Or `\bnot check\b[^\d\n]*$` if there should not be any digit anymore till the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava & @the. I tried a similar pattern `\s*(?!\d)`. It didn't work either. What's the difference between yours and mine?

Comment: Use regex101.com to see how the regexp is being matched.

Comment: The difference is that `\s*` can match a zero-length string. So it backtracks and matches `not check` followed by zero spaces. Since that isn't followed by a digit, the pattern matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\D*` in `not\s*check\s*\D*` means *match up to the first digit*, not *match ony if there is no digit ahead*.

Use

```py
\bnot\s+check\b(?!\s*\d)\D*
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/aHIrVh/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  not                      'not'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  check                    'check'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \D*                      non-digits (all but 0-9) (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```